# Does "consolidation" of query statements improve query performance?

Tags: optimization, mariadb, query

Assume we have a set of postal addresses A1, A2, A3, ... of the form:

```
A1 = 124, "Smith", "Rd"
A2 = 142, "Jones", "St"
A3 = 8190, "Smith", "Ln"
A4 = 142, "Via Gracia", NULL
A5 = 190, "Jones", "St"
A6 = 31425, "Wedgewood", "Cir"
A7 = 810, "Via Gracia", NULL
...
```

where A_N is a vector of 3 components: StreetNumberN, StreetNameN, StreetSuffixN.

No two vectors are ever equal component-for-component, however many share StreetName and StreetSuffix.

Translating this dataset directly into a SQL conditional, using a loop, one might obtain:

```
WHERE
    (StreetNumber = 124 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Rd")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 142 AND StreetName = "Jones" AND StreetSuffix = "St")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 8190 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Ln")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 142 AND StreetName = "Via Gracia")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 190 AND StreetName = "Jones" AND StreetSuffix = "St")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 31425 AND StreetName = "Wedgewood" AND StreetSuffix = "Cir")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 810 AND StreetName = "Via Gracia")
```

Now, when the StreetName and StreetSuffix match for two condition statements, it is logically possible to  "consolidate" StreetNumbers:

```
WHERE
    (StreetNumber = 124 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Rd")
 OR
    (StreetNumber IN(142, 190) AND (StreetName = "Jones" AND StreetSuffix = "St"))
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 8190 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Ln")
 OR
    (StreetNumber IN (142,810) AND StreetName = "Via Gracia")
 OR
    (StreetNumber = 31425 AND StreetName = "Wedgewood" AND StreetSuffix = "Cir")
```

Please keep in mind this is just a toy example to demonstrate the principle of "consolidation" that I mean. In practice, there would be many such "consolidations" to perform.

Is there/should there be any performance benefit in consolidating StreetNumbers as demonstrated above?

Comment: Why is query compactness a concern? Are you reaching the size limit? Why is "easier on the parser" a concern? Is parsing a significant contributor to the overall query execution time?

Comment: @mustaccio - query compactness is not a concern, and we are not hitting query size limits. By "easier on the query parser", I meant in the sense of the database generating an execution plan that is more performant. Parsing is not a significant contributor to query time. However execution time seems to be reduced with "consolidated" queries. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Transforming Boolean expressions is among the simplest tasks for the optimizer. So as long as the execution plan doesn't indicate that something really stupid is happening, I'd not worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonable question.  Let me set you straight on the relative costs of various components of the query.

`OR` is the de-optimizer.  Either of those formulations will work this way:

- Scan the *entire* table
- For each row, check the `WHERE` clause
- Most or all of the OR parts will be evaluated to eliminate a given row, thereby making your suggest a small improvement.

Scanning the table and fetching every row is the most costly part.  Evaluating the `WHERE` is a minor part.

That is, any savings you get will be insignificant in the big picture.  And, focusing on getting rid of `OR` *may* provide more gain.

If you have a million rows in the table, then this formulation will run much faster:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE (StreetNumber = 124 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Rd")
UNION ALL
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE (StreetNumber = 142 AND StreetName = "Jones" AND StreetSuffix = "St")
UNION ALL
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE (StreetNumber = 8190 AND StreetName = "Smith" AND StreetSuffix = "Ln")
...
```

but there are issues with such.  You will need an index:

```
INDEX(StreetNumber, StreetName, StreetSuffix)  -- (in any order)
```

If there might be duplicates, then use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL`.

For up to a few hundred rows, just write it whatever is simplest for you (eg, `OR` without optimization).

You will soon find that your model for addresses is incomplete.  What about "Apt. 123" or "c/o ...".  Etc.  There is probably no good reason to split an `address` into multiple columns -- simply have a single string with all the parts written in a way that facilitates displaying.  Eliminating the `AND` would be a tiny optimization.

Comment: Yep there are a lot of things that can also be added to an address such as building or floor. https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_003.htm

Comment: And that's just the US standards!  Europe strays farther.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the clear, detailed explanation! This will help me immensely. Well aware of the cornucopia of address formats, believe it or not I am working directly with an MLS database - their design decision, not mine ;-) Also, did not include all the columns - there are other columns for StreetDir, Prefix, etc.

Comment: Build your own table with all those columns concatenated.